# Unity Navmesh destroy Obstacle

Tags: unity-game-engine, path, destroy, navmesh

I have a basic NavMesh setup in Unity. A plane, an Agent and a destination.
So far, my Agent follows the path to its destination.

When i Place an obstacle in its way, it will stop at the obstacle.

Is there a way to tell the Agent (or the obstacle?) to be destroyed, when the Path is completely blocked?

When the Agent can walk around the obstacle, I am fine with that. But a complete block should lead to the destruction of the obstacle (destruction in the moment the agent "touches" the obstacle)

I hope you understand the problem.

Comment: Navmesh is just that it generates paths. If you want destruction. You will need to code that on collision

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a new obstacle is created, you can use [`NavMeshAgent`'s `CalculatePath` method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent.CalculatePath.html).  Given a target position, it will return `true` and fill out the `path` parameter if a path is found; it will return `false` if a path isn't found.  You can use the result of this method to determine whether or not your obstacle should be deleted.

Keep in mind there is a chance this method returns `true` but the `path` has a [`status`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshPathStatus.html) field that could have the value `NavMeshPathStatus.PathPartial`.  Because of this, you'll want to be sure you're checking both the return value of `CalculatePath` as well as the [`status`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshPathStatus.html) value of the `path`.